# class java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while saving data in Oracle database

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g

I have an excel sheet with about 25,000 rows. Each row in the excel sheet will be a row in my table as well. I tried to do the following and it just keeps me giving Memory out of bound exception. I tried to change the batchSize from 25 to 50, 100, 500. None of them works. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? changing the heap size of the JVM is not an option for me.

```
public void saveForecast(List list) throws FinderException{
    final Session session = getCurrentSession();
    final int batchSize = 25;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
    int rowCount = list.size();
    String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO DMD_VOL_UPLOAD (ORIGIN, DESTINATION, DAY_OF_WEEK, EFFECTIVE_DATE, DISCONTINUE_DATE, VOLUME)";
    sqlStatement += " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    System.out.println(sqlStatement);
    System.out.println("Number of rows to be inserted: "+ rowCount);
    System.out.println("Starting time: "+new Date().toString());
    try{
        con = session.connection();
        for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++){
            ForecastBatch forecastBatch = (ForecastBatch) iterator.next();              
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);             
            pstmt.setString(1, forecastBatch.getOrigin());
            pstmt.setString(2, forecastBatch.getDestination());
            pstmt.setInt(3, forecastBatch.getDayOfWeek());

            java.util.Date effJavaDate = forecastBatch.getEffectiveDate();
            java.sql.Date effSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(effJavaDate.getTime());                
            pstmt.setDate(4,  effSqlDate);              
            java.util.Date disJavaDate=forecastBatch.getDiscontinueDate();
            java.sql.Date disSqlDate =  new java.sql.Date(disJavaDate.getTime());   

            pstmt.setDate(5, disSqlDate);               
            pstmt.setInt(6, forecastBatch.getVolumeSum());

            pstmt.addBatch();
            if(i % batchSize == 0){
                pstmt.executeBatch();
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
        pstmt.executeBatch();
        pstmt.close();
        System.out.println("Ending Time: "+ new Date().toString());
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new FinderException(e);
    }
    finally{
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Few things I see 1) you're using a for loop and an iterator to traverse your list - you should use one or the other (I'd vote for the iterator).  Also what happens with a smaller excel file?  At what point does it choke?

Comment: generate a heap dump and use a memory profiler.  then you won't have to guess what is causing the issues.

Comment: What is the size on disk of your spreadsheet. What reader implementation are you using?

Comment: Hook up visualVM to your app an see what classes are eating up the memory. (I'm guessing the Hibernate Session)

Comment: I used a smaller excel file with only ten rows and set the batch batchSize=2. What should have happened is that after every 2 iteration of the loop, it should execute the batchExecute() and it does. But it seems that only the last statement in the batch gets executed. So I end up with only 5 rows in my database. My loop does go through each row in the excelsheet. The size of the excelsheet is 2.34 mb

Comment: Since there's no such thing as a "Memory out of bound exception", start by posting the actual stacktrace so we can see the real exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new statement inside your loop but only closing the last statement after the loop ends.  That means you're actually creating 25000 statements and closing only a single one leaving 24999 statements open, which I'm not surprised is causing you to run out of resources.

Furthermore, you're not using the batch statements correctly (you'd have to create the statement once, then set the parameters, call addBatch, set more parameters, call addBatch again, and so on, then call executeBatch when you want to submit all values in the batch.

EDIT:

You'll probably fix this by moving the prepareStatement call just before the for loop and I don't think calling session flush/clear is necessary either.

Comment: I moved the prepareStatement outside the for loop and it worked when I ran it this morning. It inserted all the 25,000 rows. I wanted to see if it could do it again. But on my second attempt to insert another 25,000 rows, the system just hangs and gives me the following message: "Thread "WebContainer : 0" (0000001e) has been active for 734917 milliseconds and may be hung. There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung. " and the execution stops. Am I using too much resources? It's only 25,000 rows at a time. Now it can't even insert 100 rows of data.

Comment: I figured out what the other problem was. I wasn't commiting. I changed the batchSize to 1000 and I was able to save 25,000 rows in 12 seconds. I think that's good enough. Thank you for all of your help. Although it would be nice to know if there is a way to make it even faster than 12 sec. I tried to increase the batch size to 5000 and it slowed down by a second.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem seems to be that you're re-preparing the statement for every single row.  You should be preparing the statement once.  This would likely lead to consuming a huge amount of memory.

Comment: Yes thank you. I put this statement outside the loop pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement); and it seems to solve that part of the problem. Upto 15,000 rows, I was able to insert into my table. Once I increased the number of rows in my excel sheet from 15,000 to 25,000, it just crashes. Basically nothing happens. What should be my next move? I will try to increase the batch size to 50 and see how it behaves.